# PostgresSQL jsonb column - problem with "."

Tags: java, json, postgresql, concordion

I'm trying to add the value to my table with a jsonb column:

```
{"prefId": 1, "prefType": "PREF", "date": "23.07.2020"}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "." is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: 23.07....
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: The token **is** valid: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=54d96d53bd8b60978f30fcbdfd910365 It seems your code sends something different to the database. I get that error message if the double quotes are removed from the date value: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c4ed3017a4170383468de34a9db760d

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in date format. Try `23/07/2020` or `23-07-2020`

Comment: It didn't help. In this case I got an error "Detail: Token "-" is invalid."